# Parallel Arrays how to turn int into string

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having problems with my homework and my professor is not responding. How do I get my arrays to return the string name of the month for the `getHighest` and `getLowest` functions?

It keeps telling me I have to add more detail, I removed code from this so I now just have the main and `getLowest` and `getHighest` functions left.  It says I still need more detail, so I am typing this to add more detail so I can submit my question.

Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void getRainfall(double[], int);  //To retrieve the user input.
double getTotal(double[], int);  //To total the rainfall amounts.
double getAverage(double[], int);  //To get the average rainfall.
double getLowest(double[], int, int&);  //Returns the lowest value, provides                 the index of the lowest value in the last parameter.
double getHighest(double[], int, int&); //Returns the highest value,     provides the index of the highest value in the last parameter.

//Global Variable
const int NUM_MONTHS = 12;

//Array names
double rainfall[NUM_MONTHS];
string month[NUM_MONTHS] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",     "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };         //Month array to hold names of months

int main()
{
    //Declare variables
    double  total, average;
    int low, high;
    string lowMonth, highMonth;

    //Call Functions
    getRainfall(rainfall, NUM_MONTHS);  //To retrieve the user input.
    total = getTotal(rainfall, NUM_MONTHS); //To total the rainfall amounts.
    average = getAverage(getTotal, NUM_MONTHS);  //To get the average rainfall.
    lowMonth = getLowest(rainfall, NUM_MONTHS, low);  //Returns the lowest value, provides the index of the lowest value in the last parameter.
    highMonth = getHighest(rainfall, NUM_MONTHS, high); //Returns the highest value, provides the index of the highest value in the last parameter.

    //Display the following:
    cout << "The total rainfall for the year is: " << total << endl;
    cout << "The average rainfall for the year is: " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << average << endl;
    cout << "Least amount of rainfall fell in: " << highMonth << endl;
    cout << "Most amount of rainfall fell in: " << lowMonth << endl;

    return 0;
}


//*******************************************************************************************
//              double getLowest(double amount[], int size)                                 *
//  Returns the lowest value, provides the index of the lowest value in the last parameter. *
//*******************************************************************************************

double getLowest(double amount[], int NUM_MONTHS, int &low)
{
    low = amount[0];  //Variable to hold lowest value.
    int lowMonth = 0; //Set low value to intial rainfall value.  //Variable to return month element location.

    for (int index = 0; index < NUM_MONTHS; index++)  
    {
        if (amount[index] < low)
        {
            low = amount[index];
            lowMonth = index;
        }
    }

    return lowMonth;
}

//*********************************************************************************************
//              double getHighest(double amount[], int size)                                  *
//  Returns the highest value, provides the index of the highest value in the last parameter. *
//*********************************************************************************************

double getHighest(double amount[], int NUM_MONTHS, int &highMonth)
{
    //high = amount[0];  //Variable to hold highest value
    months = amount[0];
    double highMonth = 0; //Variable to hold highest value

    for (int index = 0; index < NUM_MONTHS; index++)    
    {
        if (amount[index] > high)
        {
            highMonth = amount[index];
            months = index;
        }
    }

    return highMonth;
}
```

Comment: Hints: Write `main` first. You can't test the other functions without `main` and figuring out how you are going to test and display the results of the functions helps you figure out how you are going write the functions. [More on Test-driven Development.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) Once yuou know what all of the functions have to look like, implement and test them one by one. Testing everything at once increases the surface area that must be checked and magnifies the effect of bugs as they build on and conceal each other.

Comment: With what you have now, why don't you just make `lowMonth` and `highMonth` in `main()` ints, and just output `month[lowMonth]` and `month[highMonth]`?

Answer (score 0):

So your question is very unclear and your code is a total mess, but I assume you want the function `getHighest` to also return a string with the name of the month?
Well, one function can only return one type of variable, but you could do it with references:

```
double getHighest(double amount[], int NUM_MONTHS, int &highMonth, string &name)
{
    //high = amount[0];  //Variable to hold highest value
    months = amount[0];
    double highMonth = 0; //Variable to hold highest value

    for (int index = 0; index < NUM_MONTHS; index++)    
    {
        if (amount[index] > high)
        {
            highMonth = amount[index];
            months = index;
            name = month[index];
        }
    }
    return highMonth;
}
```

But generally your code has quite some flaws: For example the overwriting of
`highMonth` could cause problems, and why do you pass `NUM_MONTHS`, even though it is globally defined? And I don't  exactly  get why this code is so overly complicated. I also think the `getHighest` and `getLowest` functions aren't even working. As a better approach I'd try a function like this:

```
double getHighest(double amount[], string &name)
{
    double highest = 0;
    double highPos = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_MONTHS; i++)
    {
        if(highest <= amount[i])
        {
            highest = amount[i];
            highPos = i;
        }
    }
    name = month[highPos];
    return highest;
}
```

Edit: Or, if you just want to return the string, you can do it like this:

string &name)
    {
        //high = amount[0];  //Variable to hold highest value
        months = amount[0];
        double highMonth = 0; //Variable to hold highest value

```
    for (int index = 0; index < NUM_MONTHS; index++)    
    {
        if (amount[index] > high)
        {
            highMonth = amount[index];
            months = index;
            name = month[index];
        }
    }
    return highMonth;
}
```

But generally your code has quite some flaws: For example the overwriting of
`highMonth` could cause problems, and why do you pass `NUM_MONTHS`, even though it is globally defined? And I don't  exactly  get why this code is so overly complicated. I also think the `getHighest` and `getLowest` functions aren't even working. As a better approach I'd try a function like this:

```
string getHighest(double amount[], string &name)
{
    double highest = 0;
    double highPos = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_MONTHS; i++)
    {
        if(highest <= amount[i])
        {
            highest = amount[i];
            highPos = i;
        }
    }
    name = month[highPos];
    return name;
}
```

Comment: The code's not a total mess. It is organized into functions and the functions mostly make sense. OP needs needs to hit the textbook a lot harder and get the syntax down and think a bit more on what they do and do not need to do in the functions. The question is unclear, though. And when the question doesn't make sense, don't answer it.

Comment: Thank you all.  I do realize it's a total mess and all over the place.  I've been reading and working on the review questions but the arrays are not clicking for me.  It's an online class and my professor isn't available while I am to work on my homework.

Comment: My question was for the getHighest and getLowest functions, I need it to return the string name rather than an int.  I just am not sure how.